# Tiny MCE plugin in bubble.io

Tags: html, tinymce

I'm using the TinyMCE plugin in bubble.io to create the text for an email. This text is part of the larger email document. Seems TinyMCE generates an entire html document - <!DOCTYP, , ... I don't want that. I just want the html of the data in the editor. Any way to configure that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting the entire HTML document from TinyMCE you have the `fullpage` plugin installed.  If you stop running the `fullpage` plugin you should only get the data the user can see in the editor.

Comment: Hmmm, didn't realize there was a fullpage plugin. Thanks! Is there a way to configure for inline css styling?